# which port is used when delegating to? How to indicate an non-standard ssh port in this case?

Tags: ansible

I run  on my controller `london` a task on a node `ascona`. The task is to copy some files from node `arbon` with `synchronize`:

```
  - name: Synchronization using rsync protocol 
      synchronize:
        mode: push
        src: /stFolder/giorgio/
        dest: /stFolder/giorgio/
      delegate_to: arbon
```

The node `arbon` is in the inventory as:

```
   arbon:
      ansible_host:  arbon.home # 10.0.0.52  #
      ansible_user:   frank  #root #
      ansible_port: 22222
```

and I have established keys to connect with ssh on `arbon` to `ascona`. I get an error "permission denied"

```
"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: frank@arbon.home: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I assume that the cause is the non-standard port? how to indicate this situation?

Comment: `Permission denied` is authentication error, i would check the sshd logs in the `arbon` host. you can use `journalctl -f -u ssh` or `sshd` for that.

Comment: thank you for the precise instruction to identify the error better - very helpful. I got the impression, I had a problem with the authentication and settled on a different solution (just `rsync` on the command line).